# I want to use python3 to parse the output of "command>systeminfo" into json

Tags: json, python-3.x, parsing

I want turn the output of the command `systeminfo` into json.
But I only need some of specific infomation.
And I have to avoid the first line (the command line), it's not always in line 1.

How can I achieve this by python3?

I save the output into .txt file.
Below is segment of the output.

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop>systeminfo
Host Name:                 COMPUTERHOPE
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
OS Version:                10.0.10586 N/A Build 10586
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
Registered Owner:          Computerhope
Registered Organization:   Computer Hope
Product ID:                00000-00000-00000-AAAAA
Original Install Date:     12/17/2015, 7:09:50 PM
System Boot Time:          3/28/2016, 6:57:39 AM
System Manufacturer:       Dell Inc.
System Model:              XPS 8300
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7 Genuine Intel ~3401
```

I want it to be like this.

```
{
    "Host Name": "COMPUTERHOPE",
    "OS Name": "Microsoft Windows 10 Pro",
    "OS Version": "10.0.10586 N/A Build 10586",
    "Original Install Date": 
    {
     "Date": "12/17/2015",
     "Time": "7:09:50 PM",
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import json, subprocess

def get_systeminfo():
    # Command to run.
    command = ['systeminfo']

    # Run the commands and get the stdout.
    with subprocess.Popen(command, universal_newlines=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as p:
        stdout, _ = p.communicate()

    return stdout


def dic_from_systeminfo(stdout):
    # Dic to store all info.
    dic = {}

    # Previous key name saved to reuse for dic values.
    prevkey = ''

    # Loop through each line of stdout and split by colon.
    for line in stdout.splitlines():
        key, sep, value = line.partition(':')

        if sep == ':':
            value = value.strip()

            if not key.startswith(' '):
                # Assign these keys with values of type dic.
                if key in ('Original Install Date', 'System Boot Time'):
                    value = {k: v.strip() for k, v in zip(('Date', 'Time'), value.split(','))}
                elif key in ('Processor(s)', 'Hotfix(s)', 'Network Card(s)'):
                    value = dict()

                # Add to dic and save key name.
                dic[key] = value
                prevkey = key
            else:
                # Remove [] characters and then add key and value to the value type dic.
                key = key.strip().replace('[', '').replace(']', '')

                if prevkey and isinstance(dic[prevkey], dict):
                    dic[prevkey][key] = value
                else:
                    print('Warning:', 'dic[' + prevkey + '] is not a dict value.')

    return dic

# Run Systeminfo and get stdout.
stdout = get_systeminfo()

# Get dic from stdout (or read file content).
dic = dic_from_systeminfo(stdout)

# Write the dic to file.
if dic:
    with open('systeminfo.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as w:
        json.dump(dic, w, indent=4)
```

The script executes the command `systeminfo` and gets the stdout.

The stdout is processed line by line in the `for` loop and then is
split into key and value by using the `str.partition` method.

If the key name does not start with a space, then it is a root key.
If it matches one of the special key names, it will be set with a
value of a dictionary type, else it will be set with the current value.
The key name is saved to `prevkey` so that if the else condition is
triggered, `prevkey` can be used as the root key and the
key and value will be set to that root key.

The square brackets are removed from the keys in the else condition,
though that can be considered an optional preference.

If the `dic` is something, then it will be written to `systeminfo.json`.

If you only want certain keys then you can save the keys of interest to
a separate dictionary and write that to file.

---

As the main code for reading from an existing file, use:

```
stdout = ''

# Read from existing file.
with open('sysinfo.txt') as r:
    stdout = r.read()

# Get dic from stdout (or read file content).
dic = dic_from_systeminfo(stdout)

# Write the dic to file.
if dic:
    with open('systeminfo.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as w:
        json.dump(dic, w, indent=4)
```

Comment: Would be clearer to the OP if you did not mix up the running of the command and retrieval of stdout with your very clean parsing of the output using `str.partition`. OP already states he has captured the output to a text file. Or break up your answer into two parts - retrieving the command output to a file, then parsing the file.

Comment: @PaulMcG, updated answer with your advice. The `get_systeminfo` function can be omitted and the file can be opened, read and the content can be passed to  `dic_from_systeminfo` function if so desire.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
But it has an error.
 `File "par.py", line 41, in dic_from_systeminfo
    dic[prevkey][key] = value
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment.`

Comment: There is another problem, because the data is given.
Can I use `with open('sysinfo.txt') as stdout` as stdout?

Comment: Your last comment, almost. Avoid `as stdout` as that sets `stdout` as the file descriptor (file handle). See my updated answer at the bottom where I use `r` as the file descriptor. Previous comment, cannot reproduce. `value` is being assigned to a dictionary so is an odd message. Try the code I posted and see if it is OK.

Comment: `dic_from_systeminfo` function now checks if `dic[prevkey]` is a `dict`. If not, will `print` a warning instead of causing an error. Only way of to cause this issue is if the `else` is triggering before the `if` condition. Example, from question sample, `Processors(s)` key should be assigned a dict value before the `else` condition inserts the following `key`, `value` pair into the `dict` value. *Still cannot reproduce. Perhaps your `sysinfo.txt` file input has been modified*.